# Activate using KMS on different domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, kms

We have a client where we have built new servers including DC,DNS servers, lets call it, 'new.com'. These servers are activated using the KMS host in our PROD domain 'main.com'.

1) Would OS license fail/deactivate if no contact is made to the KMS host atleast once in every 180 days ?
2) Would I need to connect each server in new.com atleast once every 180 days, to the KMS host in 'main.com' to renew the license ? If yes, is there any other/easier way to make sure the licenses on servers in 'new.com' do not get deactivated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: as per documentation that is the whole sense of a KMS.

2: Sure, do not use a KMS - use a MAK (Multi Activation Key).

The whole sense of a KMS is to facilitate temporary activations under the condition that the machine connects to the KMS once per 180 days. Not every scenario supports a KMS nicely - if it does not fit, there are other ways to activate machines.